# Escaping a single character using a character class

Tags: regex

In a regular expression, the normal way to use a special character (`\^$.|?*+()[]{}`) as a literal is, of course, to escape it with a backslash:

```
\+\.
```

But I have occasionally seen code that uses a character class to achieve the same thing:

```
[+][.]
```

Now obviously that isn't the primary purpose of a character class, which is normally used to match one of several characters. While the second example uses more keystrokes, you could argue that it's also more readable.

So is there any good reason not do this (performance or otherwise)? Or does it simply come down to personal stylistic preference?

I know this isn't an earth-shattering issue—it's just a little question that has been niggling away at the back of my mind for a while, and I've not been able to find any specific mention of it elsewhere.

Comment: Hey rather than just downvoting the question and running off, how about explaining why you think "This question does not show any research effort … is unclear, or not useful"? As for research effort, I searched the web and Stack Overflow before posting. I'm not sure how I could make the question any clearer, and as for being useful, that's subjective I guess. For anyone considering adopting this style, it's a useful question I think!

Answer (score 1):

I tend to view using a character class as a means of escaping a single character as a side-effect of character classes, which is not their primary purpose.  The main reason for a character class is to represent a *range* of characters, not just a single character.

So, one possibly negative thing about the pattern `[+][.]` is that it might leave a future reader of your regex wondering if you did not intend to include more than one character in the character class.  And perhaps, given certain conditions, that reader might even change the pattern to "fix" it, by adding characters to the class which he perceives as having been wrongfully omitted.

There might be slight performance advantage to using `\+` over `[+]`, in that the latter might require the regex engine to compile a formal list (with just one character in it).  But, I would expect performance differences to be minimal.

Comment: Thanks for those thoughts Tim. Yes, normally we would think of this behaviour as a side-effect of character classes like you say. I did acknowledge that it wasn't their primary purpose. I suppose anything unusual could be perceived as a mistake by others, but I certainly didn't think that when I first saw it in someone else's code.

Comment: @Kal Just sharing my own personal opinion.  I often use `[+]` as well, but only for readability.

Comment: No worries, and thanks for sharing that you use it sometimes too! I guess it does just come down to stylistic preference. I didn't want to assume that was the case without having seen any discussion on the topic.